# Qual seria a forma ''correta'' para declarar variáveis em PHP OO?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, sintaxe

Estou começando a estudar OO e cai na seguinte dúvida:

```
<?php

class Caneta {
    var $modelo;
    var $cor;
    var $ponta;
    var $carga;
    var $tampada;
}
```

OU assim:

```
<?php

   class Caneta {
      public $modelo;
      public $cor;
      public $ponta;
      public $carga;
      public $tampada;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`var` é considerado obsoleto e não deveria ser mais usado em códigos novos, foi uma época que criaram a classe mas não queriam ser outra linguagem, mas depois mudaram de ideia e resolveram que teria todas as diversas visibilidades de um membro que outras linguagens tinham, então passou ter `private`, `protected` e `public`, portanto este é usado entre as duas possibilidades apresentadas.

Desta forma você deixa claro que a variável é pública, com a palavra chave antiga ficava público mas não deixava isso claro, até porque não podia ser outra coisa. Já que mudou a filosofia da linguagem faz mais sentido mesmo.

Há detratores dessa ideia, mas a posição oficial é essa.